# Fix carousel images size whenever change image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

**My Problem**

I am using exact same code from bootstrap website for carousel. But whenever loading next image, the whole div changing height and width. I already made `fixed height, 100% width, overflow:hidden` etc based on some suggestions from stack overflow forums. But it is not working.

**My Codes**

```css
.carousel-item img {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://intrepidmorocco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Desert-Tours-marrakech.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://moroccotraveland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/desert-morocco-sahara.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://artofabsence.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/camel-ride1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: are the images have the same height , and wiche element did you fix it's height

Comment: images having different height and width. I fixed height for all images and width to 100% to all images. But its not working

Comment: undo that let the images have `width:100%;` and let the height to auto , give `.carousel-inner{height:yourheight px; overflow:hidden}`

Comment: @M0ns1f: Tried that. But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the width fixed now so it wont resize anymore. `width: 100vw;`. For me the height was already fixed! Hopefully this is what you need.

```css
.carousel-item img {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100vw;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://intrepidmorocco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Desert-Tours-marrakech.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://moroccotraveland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/desert-morocco-sahara.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://artofabsence.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/camel-ride1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you dont want the image to lose its ratio, try object-fit:cover. It will crop the image but maintain its ratio.

Comment: This showing the same result as before. it doesn't pull the image all the way to edges.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes to completely fill the viewport. :)

Comment: Just change width:100vw to suit you needs!!

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I already gave tick to your answer. And with  object-fit:cover, this works like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem by combining jumbotron and some other adjustment. See my codes below

```css
.carousel-item img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 56px;/*This padding is just to adjust the image for my page only.      Can be removed                      or adjusted accordingly*/
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; /*Adding this also just to suit my page situation. Please change it accordingly */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="jumbotron">
  <div id="carou">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://intrepidmorocco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Desert-Tours-marrakech.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://moroccotraveland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/desert-morocco-sahara.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://artofabsence.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/camel-ride1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```